# Calling method from view in model collection?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I've done a method in the model that gets the different genres I need to show in the registration and it works well.

```
@model project1.Models.Location
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, Model.GenreDropDown())
```

Here's the method in my model:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GenreDropDown()
{
    var db2 = new UsersContext();
    var genreList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in db2.Genre)
    {
        genreList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.GenreName,
                                           Text = item.GenreName });
    }

    return genreList;
}
```

The problem is that I want to do the same at another view, but it gets this from the controller:

```
@model List< project1.Models.Location>
```

Any smooth suggestions on how to do this with razor? I'm kind of new to it.

Also, the space at @model is intended, it got interpreted as something and didn't show.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MVC EditorTemplates. To create the editor template you need to create folder named **EditorTemplates** under **~/Views/Shared/** folder. In this folder you create view with the name match as the model class name -- in this case the view name is **Location**.

Here's the content of **Location.cshtml**:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Location
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, Model.GenreDropDown())
</div>
```

And on your view you just simply write this:

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.Location>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```